# How do I write data to a file, and not just print to console window

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this

```
print dt(), socket.gethostname(), " at ", getIP('eth0')
print "---------------------------------------------------------"
print "Temperature: ", CPU_temp,"F"
print "CPU Usage: ", CPU_Usage
print "Current RAM usage is: ", RAM_used, " Used. Of ", RAM_total, " RAM free is ", RAM_free
print "Current size of disk is: ", DISK_total, " Size of disk used ", DISK_used, " size of disk remaining ", DISK_free
```

using with open

```
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/stats.txt", "a") as log:
    data = write_stats()
    log.write(str(data))
```

but can only write it to a console window

Comment: This is a general programming question but does not belong to Raspberry Pi. You should consider to ask at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014688/).

Comment: Python comes with amazing logging tools.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/using-the-logging-python-class-to-write-to-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function that accepts multiple parameters:

```
def log(*params):
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/stats.txt", "a") as log:
        for param in params:
            log.write(str(param)+' ')
        log.write('\n')

log('a','b','c','d')
log('e',1,'f')
log('g',1.1)
```

Resulting file:

```
a b c d 
e 1 f 
g 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution without rewriting your code is to direct stdout to a file with bash redirection `>`.

`python3 mypythonprogramwithprint.py > /home/pi/desktop/stats.txt`

If you want to write the file in python you'll need to change all of those `print` calls into `log.write(...)` calls.

Comment: how when I just tried it on the first one I get a function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given) ??